# how to implement external login provders(linkedin) login using .net core with openidconnect?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

tried linkedin login in asp.net core.

Added below code in startup

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:LinkedInConfiguration:Scheme").Value, "linkedin", options =>
               {
                   options.SignInScheme = "Identity.External";
                   options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:LinkedInConfiguration:ClientId").Value;
                   options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:LinkedInConfiguration:ClientSecret").Value;
                   options.CallbackPath = Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:LinkedInConfiguration:CallbackPath").Value;
                   options.Authority = "https://www.linkedin.com";
                   options.Scope.Add("openid");
                   options.Scope.Add("email");
                   options.Scope.Add("profile");
                   options.SaveTokens = true;
               });
```

I got error like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgCrk.png

Comment: the reason behind the error shows that might be issue obtaining the configuration from the LinkedIn OpenID Connect provider. possible reasons such as incorrect client ID and client secret, misconfigured callback URL, or network connectivity issues.Verify that you have provided the correct LinkedIn client ID and client secret in the ConfigureServices method of your Startup.cs file.Ensure that the callback URL specified in the LinkedIn developer portal matches the CallbackPath value in the ConfigureServices method. The callback URL should be in the format https://yourdomain.com/signin-linkedin.

Comment: I have given correct details of clientid, secret and callback path url as https://localhost:44363/signin-linkedin. Still getting same issue.

Comment: Could you try setting IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII flag to true. This will show the PII information in the error, which might give you more insight.

Comment: I added IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to true , still not working , and getting logs

Message: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.

Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'Client authentication failed', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'

Comment: does it show some more detailed error ?

Comment: I am getting logs like below

System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'Client authentication failed', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)

Comment: could you  regenerate the client credentials in the LinkedIn Developer portal and update them in your application. add below code in the appsettings.json:`"ExternalLoginConfiguration": {
  "LinkedInConfiguration": {
    "Scheme": "LinkedIn",
    "ClientId": "your-client-id",
    "ClientSecret": "your-client-secret"
  }
}`